# PHP mysqli_fetch_all gives me a blank screen

Tags: php, mysqli

I just pushed something from my local machine to the live site and I get blank pages everywhere. I tracked down the problem to mysqli_fetch_all when I use that everything breaks. Why is it doing this? and how do I fix it? if I use mysqli_fetch_array or mysqli_fetch_row or mysqli_fetch_assoc it works but my data is not displayed properly.

This is one the functions that is breaking:

```
function getUserFields($connection){

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "DESCRIBE `adminUsers`");
        $results = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $results;

}
```

The `$connection` is the connection to my database, I have confirmed that works and $query sting is getting populated, it just the `mysqli_fetch_all` does not work, how could I fix this in the function without adjusting how the data is displayed currently.

Comment: This function doesn't actually print anything to screen.  Do you do that outside this function?

Comment: Turn `error_reporting` on, and `display_errors`

Comment: yes outside the function. I have my functions in a class which are called in the controller and display on a view.

Comment: you can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `mysqli_fetch_all()` and its object oriented counterpart (`mysqli_result::fetch_all)` are only available in PHP 5.3 and later.

It appears your server is running a lower version of PHP, or you're missing [MySQL Native Driver (which this function depends on)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php), which explains why the other fetch functions work and this doesn't.

From the [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

> mysqli_fetch_all
>   mysqli_result::fetch_all
>   **(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)**

For future debugging, turn errors on or refer to your error log because this will usually help to identify the problem.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

If you don't have access to upgrade the PHP version, or install MySQLND, you can simply convert the code to manually iterate using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`:

```
function getUserFields($connection){
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "DESCRIBE `adminUsers`");    
    $results = array();

    if($query){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $results[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per php documentation, this function is **mysqlnd only** (MySQL native driver). If you do not have it installed on the server, it will not execute (and throw errors).

> Available only with mysqlnd.
>
> As mysqli_fetch_all() returns all the rows as an array in a single
>   step, it may consume more memory than some similar functions such as
>   mysqli_fetch_array(), which only returns one row at a time from the
>   result set. Further, if you need to iterate over the result set, you
>   will need a looping construct that will further impact performance.
>   For these reasons mysqli_fetch_all() should only be used in those
>   situations where the fetched result set will be sent to another layer
>   for processing.

Visit http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-mysqlnd for more information about this.

**Consider using mysqli_fetch_array** instead - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php. It uses almost the same parameters, so there shouldn't be a problem.

There is a possibility that the problem lies elsewhere, but this would be my first guess (with no error reporting enabled yet :/)

EDIT: 
You will need to iterate over the results, because mysqli_fetch_array (and other functions from this family) returns **one row at a time**. This is probably why you have the results wrong when using them.

Other solution would be enabling php_mysqlnd.dll/php_mysqlnd.so extension in the php.ini on the server and restarting the service (you probably have in on the local machine, and that's why it works)